# evaluate a list in one line code in python

Tags: python

I created a function to evaluate list if they have duplicates or not:

```
def duplica(list_to_check):
    if len(set(list_to_check)) != len(list_to_check):
        print('there are duplicates inside the list')
        result = 0  
    else:
        result = 1
    
    return result

print(duplica([1, 1, 2]))

##test it:
there are duplicates inside the list 
0
```

I want to know if there's any alternative way to evaluate the list using a code of only one line (for example lambda or map)

Comment: no, it don't answer

Comment: It does for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the value:

```
0 if len(set(list_to_check)) != len(list_to_check) else 1
```

or even better (): (provided by: `Olvin Roght` in the comment)

```
int(len(set(list_to_check)) == len(list_to_check))
```

With print:

```
(0,print('there are duplicates inside the list'))[0] if len(set(list_to_check)) != len(list_to_check) else 1
```

Comment: Bool can be used in operations as integer normally, so you don't even need `int()`.